# Flash player not detecting camcorder video through capture card

Tags: flash, actionscript, video-capture, rtmp

We have developed live streaming platform with RTMP and HTTP streaming using adobe flash player and action script. We are successfully streaming via webcam but when video is given via camcorder and capture card we are not able to detect the camera in the flash player. How do we enable it ?

Answer (score 0):

Hell Vijay,

If you make a right click in the player and select "parameters" do you see your devices in the camera tab of Adobe Flash Player? If not I think it is a connection issue and you may search in your device's manual

Comment: hi thomas, we are detecting capture card names in camera list but not getting  camera feed.

Comment: Ok, that's strange, do you succeed to see the camera video from another software? Let us know with [this sample code](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSfffb011ac560372f3fa68e8912e3ab6b8cb-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d2c) what are the flash properties of your camera (you just have to set the good name/index in _Camera.getCamera()_)